# Symfony translations not working

Tags: symfony, twig, translation

I have done the following checklist:

1. created translation file respecting format domain.lang.loader
2. cleared cache
3. checked that language catalogue is created in cache folder

Though in my twig template file,

```
{{ 'message'|trans }}
```

never translates.

Where can I look next in order to make translations work?

Is there any chance that **[Doctrine Translatable Extension](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/translatable.md)** that I am using generates some kind of conflicts?

Comment: Where are you trying to use the translations? Form, controller, template?

Comment: Trying to use it from template

Comment: try to reproduce the problem on a fresh fork of symfony-standard (with same version as yours), and share it. It's difficult to know without your whole app/config, composer.json, and result of app/check.php

Comment: Meanwile, can you **explicitly** give what you've done ? "created traslation file respecting format domain.lang.loader" does not say it's correct :) Where did you put the file for example ? What exact name?

Comment: Which version of Symfony are you using?

Comment: @Florian: I have a "messages.en.yml" in /src/Namespace/BundleName/Resources/translations.

Comment: @Mark: I use Symfony "2.2.*"

Comment: is the bundle registered in AppKernel ?

Comment: @Florian Yes, it is, I have a backend app running, with db translations for entities, frontend is runing fine too. Only this "static" translations are not working.. And there is only one bundle for all, so no issue here.

Comment: sometimes, clearing cache with the `cache:clear` command is not enough. Have you tried removing all the files under cache folder manually? Or clear cache without warming up (--no-warmup)?

Comment: I ran in the same problem. My problem as a Symfony2 beginner was that I had followed the documentation word by word: So I ended up with a `config.yml` two separate sections named `framework`. The section containing the translator configuration has been ignored.

I merged the two sections `framework` and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 26):

In Symfony 3.0 I had to clear the cache:

```
php bin/console cache:clear
```

I see you already did that, maybe it helps other like me.

Answer (score 25):

Have you enabled the Translator service in your config file?

```
framework:
    translator: { fallbacks: en }
```

The language catalogue is created in your cache folder irrespective of whether your translator is enabled or not.

Did you try translating in your controller?

```
$trans = $this->get('translator')->trans('message');
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to confirm.. Of course, config is not commented.

Answer (score 18):

Try to [specify domain](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#using-message-domains). If you not specify domain by default it a messages.

```
{{ 'message'|trans({}, 'some_domain') }}
```

Then translations can be found in

- the kernel root directory/Resources/translations directory;
- the kernel root directory/Resources/bundle name/translations
  directory;
- the Resources/translations/ directory of the bundle.

For example `some_domain.fr.yml`. Last step is to configure your locale. You can get current locale from request with `$request->getLocale()`

P.S. try to `rm -r app/cache` to make sure that the cache is deleted

Comment: The domain is the default one (messages - I got a messages.en.yml). It just doesn't want to work. I have also cleared cache (multiple times :)

Comment: thats about `$request->getLocale()`?

Comment: `cache:clear` didn't work for me, I had to do `rm -r var/cache/dev/translations` (Symfony 4)

Answer (score 8):

I could use one of the translations, but not the other and didn't know why. If you have troubles with translations also, read this.

First, standard checklist:

- Make sure [you enabled and configured translator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#configuration).
- Make sure [translation is in proper place](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#translation-resource-file-names-and-locations) and follows [proper naming convenction](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#the-translation-processl) ( domain(messages by default).lang_code.file_format ).
- Clear cache using `php app/console cache:clear` command.
- Try to manually call `$this->getRequest()->setLocale('en');` in Controller, also you may try to use `$this->get('translator')->trans('Some message');` directly in your Controller.
- If it still doesn't work, make sure BOM isn't in your translated file. That was my case.

Watch out for [`BOM`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) in the translated file. The translator who translates the yml file used UTF8 which is OK, but editor he used leaved BOM at the beginning of the file. This is dangerous probably because of [PHP's UTF8 BOM bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=22108) as it adds few invisible characters to first section of your file.

Btw, [debugging your translations](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#debugging-translations) may be very helpful, too.

Answer (score 6):

According to the [Symfony Translations Documentation page](http://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html), if you are not using a [Service Container](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html) for your translation purpose, these are simple steps to go:

1. [Enable and configure](http://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html#translation-configuration) Symfony's translation service.

   - YAML

     ```
     framework:
         translator: { fallbacks: [en] }
     ```
   - PHP

     ```
     $container->loadFromExtension('framework', array(
         'translator' => array('fallbacks' => array('en')),
     ));
     ```
2. Abstract strings (i.e. "messages") by wrapping them in calls to the Translator ("[Basic Translation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html#translation-basic)").

   ```
   public function indexAction()
   {
       $translated = $this->get('translator')->trans('Symfony is great');

       return new Response($translated);
   }
   ```
3. [Create translation resources/files](http://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html#translation-resources) for each supported locale that translate each message in the application.

   Symfony looks for message files (i.e. translations) in the following default locations:

   - the `app/Resources/translations` directory;
   - the `app/Resources/<bundle name>/translations` directory;
   - the `Resources/translations/` directory inside of any bundle.

     **Translation File Name**

     The filename of the translation files is also important: each message file must be named according to the following path:  **domain**.**locale**.**loader** (e.g. filename: `navigation.en.xlf`):

     - domain: An optional way to organize messages into groups (e.g. `admin`, `navigation` or the default `messages`) - see [Using Message Domains](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/translation.html#using-message-domains);
     - locale: The locale that the translations are for (e.g. en_GB, en, etc);
       loader: How Symfony should load and parse the file (e.g. xlf, php, yml, etc).
     - The loader can be the name of any registered loader. By default, Symfony provides many loaders, including:

       - `xlf`: **XLIFF** file;
       - `php`: **PHP** file;
       - `yml`: **YAML** file.

         The choice of which loader to use is entirely up to you and is a matter of taste. **The recommended option is to use `xlf` for translations**.
4. Determine, [set and manage the user's locale](http://symfony.com/doc/current/translation/locale.html) for the request and **optionally** [on the user's entire session](http://symfony.com/doc/current/session/locale_sticky_session.html).
5. Clear the cache:

   ```
   php bin/console c:c
   ```

---

**The Translation Process**

To actually translate the message, Symfony uses a simple process:

- The locale of the current user, which is stored on the request is determined;
- A catalog (e.g. big collection) of translated messages is loaded from translation resources defined for the locale (e.g. fr_FR). Messages from the fallback locale are also loaded and added to the catalog if they don't already exist. The end result is a large "dictionary" of translations.
- If the message is located in the catalog, the translation is returned. If not, the translator returns the original message.

Answer (score 1):

This helped me to get it worked, since clearing the cache also didn't help.

**Symfony 4.6.2:**

Try this command to update translation files:

`php bin/console translation:update --dump-messages --force de`

(Source: https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html#configuration)

Comment: Symfony 4.6 are you sure ?

Answer (score 0):

I can already answer your 2 questions:

1: you can look at

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Extension/TranslationExtension.php#L97
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Translation/Translator.php
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Translation/Translator.php#L174

2: If you're talking about gedmo doctrine extensions, or Knplabs DoctrineBehaviors, no, there is no way it conflicts with symfonys's translator. These are 2 independant pieces.

Answer (score 0):

Just faced the same issue and fixed it by `$this->get('translator')->setLocale('fr');` in the controller action. I fixed it by adding `{_locale}` in the route path.

Comment: Also fixed it by adding {_locale} in route path